# How to clear a specific line in the shell in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a very simple statistics calculator that calculates the sum, variance, average of a group of values that the user submits. It is working as intended so far but one thing I have been noticing is how every time the user inputs a value, the python shell prints a new line (as seen in the image) I was just wondering how I could make it so that the only thing that clears out is the line where the user inputs the value instead of just creating a new line.

```
# Introduction
print ('Statisticcs Calculator --- Made by Aksel')
print()
print ('Type "help" to see all the different calculations you can make')
print()
print ('===============================================================')
print()
print ('Please Input a Value for Your List')
print()
print ('Type "stop" to finish inputting values')
print()
print ('======================================')

# Functions for different calculations
def print_grades(grades_input):
  for grade in grades_input:
    print ("Student Grade: {}".format(grade))

def grades_sum(scores):
  total = 0
  for score in scores: 
    total += score
  return total
  print ("Sum of Grades: {}".format(grades_sum(user_list)))

def grades_average(grades_input):
  sum_of_grades = grades_sum(grades_input)
  average = sum_of_grades / float(len(grades_input))
  return average
  print ("Class Average: {}".format(grades_average(user_list)))

def grades_variance(scores):
  average = grades_average(scores)
  variance = 0
  for score in scores:
    avgscr = average - score
    variance += avgscr ** 2
  return variance / len(scores)
  print ("The Variance: {}".format(grades_variance(user_list)))

def grades_std_deviation(variance):
  return variance ** 0.5
  print ('Standard Deviaton: {}'.format(grades_std_deviation(variance)))

# Creating the list of values
user_list = []
lps = 'whatever'
while lps:
    print ()

# I want this to stay on the same line even after the user submits their input        
    usrinput = input('Value: ')
    print()

    if usrinput.isdigit():
        user_list.append(usrinput)
        print()
        print ('Value has been stored')
        print()
    elif usrinput == 'stop' or usrinput == 'Stop':
        print()
        print ('All values have been stored.')
        print()
        input()
        break

        break
    else:
        print()
        print ('Only Numbers are Allowed as Values')
        print()

    if usrinput == 'stop' or usrinput == 'Stop':
        break

print (', '.join(user_list)) # This is just for me to debug and make sure the list only stores numbers
input()

# Program still in progress some features missing
```

I am using **Python 3.5**

I know os.system('cls') exists but that clears the whole screen and I don't want that

for a reference on how it looks here's an image:

[Image of the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgBnr.jpg)

Comment: `\n` is used for a newline. `\r` is return carriage on the same line. You could try that.

Comment: General advice: Python indent is 4 spaces, not 2, and certainly not 2 in half of the program, and 4 in the other half. Consistent code formatting matters.

Comment: @Tomalak Yeah it's my first time using Stack overflow and I kind of messed up the indentation but overall thank you for the advice!

Comment: So the core question is *"How can I make a console program in Python that has better control over where on the screen an input prompt appears?"* - The answer to that is: Use [curses](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/curses.html). The question is if it's the right time to increase program complexity this much this early, i.e. before your program actually has all the functionality you want it to have. Making the UI nice should come after making the program work.

Comment: On another note, Python has a built-in `sum()` function that adds up numbers from a list. Your `grades_sum` function can be replaced with a single call - `sum(grades_input)`.

Comment: @Tomalak oh okay thank you! and yeah I understand I should focus more on making my program functional rather than tweaking its appearance, it was just bothering me and I was curious as to what the solution is; moreover, I am well aware of the sum() function but I just wanted to test myself and see if I could come up with a function that's equivalent but thank you nonetheless!